# Create a Two-Dimensional Integer Array using an One-Dimensional Array

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am stumped on how I would go about making a function that creates a 2-D integer array from two integer values labelled rows and cols which are used in a 1-D array which is then in turn, used to create the 2-D array.

I am trying to use two parameters which are number of rows and number of columns of the array that I want to be emulating.  I want to return a pointer to the data structure that needs to be dynamically allocated that has enough space to hold the array

Comment: What, specifically are you looking for help with?

Comment: @Daniel I want to know how to create a 2D array with a 1D array.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't completely understand what you mean, but I'll try my best to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

To implement an array with `R` rows and `C` columns with elements of type `T`, one can allocate memory with:

```
T *MyArray = malloc(R * C * sizeof *MyArray);
if (!MyArray) ReportError…
```

Then one can access the element in row `r` and column `c` with:

```
MyArray[r*C + c] = NewValue; // Set element [r, c] to NewValue.

T Value = MyArray[r*C + c]; // Get value of element [r, c].
```

One can free the memory with:

```
free(MyArray);
```

To build a fancier interface to such arrays, you can use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef int T;

typedef struct { T *A; size_t R, C; } Array2D;


void ReportError(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, something went wrong.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Create a 2D array.
Array2D CreateArray2D(size_t R, size_t C)
{
    Array2D X = { malloc(R * C * sizeof *X.A), R, C };
    if (!X.A) ReportError();
    return X;
}


// Destroy a 2D array, releasing its memory.
void DestroyArray2D(Array2D X)
{
    free(X.A);
}


// Set the value of an element in a 2D array.
void SetArray2DElement(Array2D X, size_t r, size_t c, T x)
{
    X.A[r*X.C + c] = x;
}


// Get the value of an element in a 2D array.
T GetArray2DElement(Array2D X, size_t r, size_t c)
{
    return X.A[r*X.C + c];
}

// Get a pointer to an element in a 2D array.
T *GetArray2DReference(Array2D X, size_t r, size_t c)
{
    return &X.A[r*X.C + c];
}


// Example use.
int main(void)
{
    Array2D A = CreateArray2D(3, 4);

    for (size_t r = 0; r < 3; ++r)
        for (size_t c = 0; c < 4; ++c)
            SetArray2DElement(A, r, c, 10*r + c);

    // Show how to use reference.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        *GetArray2DReference(A, i, i) = 100*i;

    for (size_t r = 0; r < 3; ++r)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < 4; ++c)
            printf(" %3d", GetArray2DElement(A, r, c));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Most C implementations support variable-length arrays, which can be used to implement two-dimensional arrays. If you do not care about being able to use the code in C implementations that do not support this, you can use:

```
T (*MyArray)[C] = malloc(R * sizeof *MyArray);
if (!MyArray) ReportError…
```

Then you can access the element in row `r` and column `c` with:

```
MyArray[r][c] = NewValue;

T Value = MyArray[r][c];
```

Answer (score 1):

One conventional way to make a 2D array out of a 1D array is to make a 1D array of pointers, each of which dynamically allocates memory. But I don't know if that's quite what you mean. If you just want to dynamically allocate a 2D integer array from two integer values labelled rows and columns, you can try something like this:

```
int **make2D(int c, int r) {
    int **arr;
    arr = malloc(c*sizeof(&c)); // Note &c is just the size of an integer pointer.
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        arr[i] = malloc(r*sizeof(r)); // Note r is just the size of an integer
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing the null checks and the overflow checks.

Comment: This method of faking a two-dimensional array appears repeatedly on Stack Overflow but is generally bad code and should not be used in production without special circumstances. It is wasteful, has poorer performance (due to pointer loads) than simply calculating an array index, and interferes with compiler optimization (since the compiler generally cannot at compile time see where the pointers point, whereas it can see array index calculations).